# OutOfMemory Exception Loading Bitmap from file

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am running into an issue where I am loading a file into a bitmap, getting the image properties that I need and then disposing of the bitmap.

```
foreach (string file in fiList)
{
    newImage = new imageInfo();
    newImage.OrigName = currFile.Name;
    newImage.Location = currFile.FullName;
    newImage.NewName = cleanFileName(newImage);
    newImage.ManualNameChange = false;
    newImage.Type = type;
    newImage.Size = Math.Round(sizeInMB, 2) + " KB";
    newImage.LastModified = currFile.LastWriteTime;
    newImage.CreateDate = currFile.CreationTime;
    tmpImage = Bitmap.FromFile(currFile.FullName);
    newImage.DPI = 
        (int)Math.Ceiling(tmpImage.HorizontalResolution);
    newImage.Width = tmpImage.Width;
    newImage.Height = tmpImage.Height;
    newImage.PixelFormat = tmpImage.PixelFormat.ToString();

    tmpImage.Dispose();

    ...
}
```

I keep getting an OutOfMemory error, but upon running a memory profiler, the appication is only using 200M of the 1.4GB that it can allocate. I looked at the image and this file is only 64MB jpg, so even after converting to a bitmap, should not be consuming much of the the 1.2GB left. The Error is happening at the `Bitmap.FromFile` Method on to create `tmpImage`

Why would I be getting an OutOfMemory Exception when I still have plenty of memory to allocate?

Comment: I see you have resolved your issue, but I just wanted to add that while the image may be 64MB on disk, it is probably compressed to some degree.  When loaded into memory in .Net it is no longer compressed so the amount of memory would be _width * height * bytes per pixel_.

Comment: That is true, which is why I stated this in my question. Even at 90% compression though, which would be quite lossy, this would still only be half of the memory remaining.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After doing some digging, this actually has nothing to do with the memory allocation of the program. This issue is actually due to trying to load a corrupt image into memory. For some reason when an image is corrupt, this causes the OutOfMemory Exception to be thrown. It is a bit of a false positive.